# Website wont scroll down when window resizes?

Tags: html, css

My website won't scroll down to the other contents of the page when the window resizes. Here is the CSS I am using. It won't let me scroll down to see my text. Ive added my CSS and html code. I'm trying to make this page but as soon as the screen is smaller it wont make me scroll down to see more of my text.

```
:root {
    font-size: 1
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML also?

Comment: @apex2022 Just added it

Comment: that `overflow:hidden` in body is prevent the body from scrolling.. remove that you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

that overflow:hidden in body is prevent the body from scrolling.. remove that you are good to go.

here is updated code snippet

```css
:root {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
html {
    overflow: scroll;
    
}
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    display: grid;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
}
.image{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 55vw;
    max-width: 40vw;
    background: url("https://marketplace.canva.com/EAD2962NKnQ/2/0/1600w/canva-rainbow-gradient-pink-and-purple-virtual-background-_Tcjok-d9b4.jpg") no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: 55vw 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    flex-grow: 3;  
} 
.container2{  
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Sign Up Form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    
        <div class="image">
            
            <div class="header">
                
                <h1>hello</h1> 
            
            </div> 
        </div>
</html>
```